# Angular 8 browser cache CORS policy issue with nodejs API

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, angular8, browser-cache, node-api

I'm facing this caching issue on my angular 8 website, it's working fine till hour and then throw CORS policy error while api call.

[image]

After I clear the browser cache and reload, it start working fine again.
Can anyone suggest a solution, for this I tried `outputHashing=all` and `cache clear --force` and `rm -rf . angular/cache` command but still getting same issue.